# How can you dynamically add new bands to the Infragistics UltraGrid control?

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I need to represent hierarchical data on the Winforms UltraGrid control. The data is contained on a BindingList object, which is assigned to BindingSource control. The objects contained in the collection have a "Children" property, which is another BindingList containing these objects.
As our data volume is high, I'm only populating the grid with the first level items. So far so good. Then I want to get the children items for a row every time the users click on it.
How can I do it? I have tried to do it on the MouseUp event, but it doesn't look good. Besides, the children objects should be retrieved and shown at the same time and at the moment I have to click several times to make them show up.

Thanks a lot.

Regards.

Comment: what version of UltraGrid are you using?

Comment: You want to dynamically add rows or bands?

Comment: Both. I need to add bands and rows dinamycally.

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, you can not add band. You can add subitem to a Children collection, and band will be created automatically.

The is special event named **BeforeRowExpanded**. It's fired when a user clicks on an expansion indicator.  You could put your data loading code there.

Check out *frmAccessView.cs* in the SamplesExplorer solution. It is avaliable in Samples package from Infragistics.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of UltraGrid you're using, but try the [BeforeCellActivate](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~BeforeCellActivate_EV.html) or [BeforeRowActivate](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~BeforeCellActivate_EV.html) events.

Comment: I have 7.3, will have a look at those events. Thanks.